# What is the use case of "!" "$" "(" ")" "+" " ," characters in URL?

Tags: url

According to [rfc3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2) the  "!" "$"  "("  ")" "+" " ," are reserved characters :

```
reserved = gen-delims / sub-delims
gen-delims = ":" / "/" / "?" / "#" / "[" / "]" / "@"
sub-delims = "!" / "$" / "&" / "’" / "(" / ")" / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
```

The reserved characters are have special meaning in URLs ,So What the special meaning (or use) of  "!" "$"  "("  )" "+" " ," characters in URL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's up to the application. The next paragraph in the RFC you quoted says:

> The purpose of reserved characters is to provide a set of delimiting characters that are distinguishable from other data within a URI. [...] Characters in the reserved set are protected from normalization and are therefore safe to be used by scheme-specific and producer-specific algorithms for delimiting data subcomponents within a URI.

`+` is used in HTTP query strings, for example. Anyone could devise a custom URI scheme that gives `!`, `$` or any of the other delimiters special meaning.

Comment: That is means that "!" "$" "(" ")"  " ," characters not have special meaning (or use) until now ? and are safe to use it in URL without percent encoding ?